# Can use different transformer model for tokenizer and model?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, roberta

Can I use roberta for tokenizer while bert for model?

```
from transformers import RobertaTokenizerFast

tokenizer = RobertaTokenizerFast.from_pretrained("./bert_tokenizer", max_len=512)

from transformers import BertForMaskedLM
config = BertConfig()
bert= BertForMaskedLM(config)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use RoBERTa tokenizer for BERT model. The reason is that the vocabulary for BERT and RoBERTa are different. Thus a word-piece token which is present in RoBERTa's vocabulary may not be present in BERT's vocabulary.

Comment: Exactly........!